# Count nodes that referenced current node in VIews

Tags: 7, views

How do I count how many nodes have referenced the current node In Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Advanced* section of the view's configuration, there is a subsection *Other*. This subsection holds an item *Use aggregation*. Turn this item on. This allows you to configure the *Aggregation settings* for each field in the *Fields* section. One option is to use COUNT.

What remains is to navigate from the current node to the nodes that reference the current node. In Drupal 6, this could be done with the [Reverse Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/reverse_node_reference) module, which suggests the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module for Drupal 7. I think you have to add a Relationship then add a Node:Nid field that uses this relationship and is aggregated using COUNT.

Comment: Aggregation + Entityreference module Solved the problem. Thanks